# Do there exist infinite-dimensional Banach spaces in which every bounded linear operator attains its norm?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, operator-theory, norms, operator-norms

Let $X$ be a Banach space, $L(X)$ the space of all bounded linear operators on $X$. We say that $A ∈ L(X)$ *attains its norm* if there exists $x ∈ X$ such that $\|x\| = 1$ and $\|Ax\| = \|A\|$. The following question sounds as a classical one, but possibly is still open.

**Question:** Does there exist an infinite-dimensional Banach space $X$ such that each $A ∈ L(X)$ attains its norm?

If such spaces exist, they should be very unusual (see related results below). If they do not exist, it would be good to know that in each infinite-dimensional Banach space there is a bounded linear operator which does not attain its norm.

**Related results and observations:**

(1) R. C. James’s characterization of reflexivity implies that if $X$ is such that each $A\in L(X)$ attains its norm, then $X$ and $L(X)$ are reflexive spaces.

(2) J. R. Holub [2] proved that if $X$ has the approximation property, then the reflexivity of $L(X)$ implies that $X$ is finite dimensional.

(3) N. J. Kalton [3, Theorem 2] proved that $L(X)$ cannot be reflexive for nonseparable $X$.

(4) Hence the only possible candidates for $X$ in the problem are separable reflexive spaces without $1$-complemented infinite-dimensional subspaces having the approximation property.

(5) Some more related results and observations can be found in [1] (see p. 693), [4], and [5].

(6) I published this question in Extracta Math., **20** (2005), 65-66, but never got any information on it.

**References:**

[1] G. Godefroy and P. Saphar, Duality in spaces of operators and smooth norms on Banach spaces, *Illinois J. Math.*, **32** (1988), no. 4, 672–695.

[2] J. R. Holub, Reflexivity of L(E, F), *Proc. Amer. Math. Soc.*, **39** (1973), 175–177.

[3] N. J. Kalton, Spaces of compact operators, *Math. Ann.*, **208** (1974), 267–278.

[4] V. A. Khatskevich, M. I. Ostrovskii, and V. S. Shulman, Extremal problems for operators in Banach spaces arising in the study of linear operator pencils, *Integral Equations and Operator Theory*, **51** (2005), 109-119.

[5] M. I. Ostrovskii, Extremal problems for operators in Banach spaces arising in the study of linear operator pencils, II, *Integral Equations and Operator Theory*,  **51** (2005) 553-564

Comment: By Argyros-Haydon there exists an $\infty$-dimensional Banach space in which every operator is scalar-plus-compact. Is it true that every scalar-plus-compact operator attains its norm?

Comment: In general this is not true, one can construct examples even in a Hilbert space. Consider $I-K$, where $K$ is an operator of coordinate-wise multiplication of a vector in $\ell_2$ by a positive strictly decreasing sequence in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @YCor typical example: diagonal matrix in $\ell^2$ with diagonal entries $1-1/n$.

Comment: We may try something like that: take a nested decreasing sequence of closed subspaces $X_i$ with trivial intersection, operator $Q_n$ should act on $X_n$ as multiplication by $(1+2^{-n})$, this is norm of $Q_n$ and $\sum \|Q_n -I\|<\infty$. Then $\prod Q_n$ works, yes? But this may be not possible in some bad spaces.

Comment: @Fedor Petrov: I am not sure that I understand what you mean. It looks like the product will not be defined, for example,on $X_1\backslash X_2$.

Comment: Thanks for these simple examples. Anyway, possibly it would make sense to consider Argyros-Haydon's spaces? do they admit bounded self-operators not attaining their norm?

Comment: $Q_n$ is defined on the whole space and acts as a scalar operator on $X_n$, attains its norm exactly on $X_n$, and is close to unity.

Comment: @YCor: The Argyros-Haydon space has the approximation property, and thus has operators which do not attain their norm by the result of Holub (mentioned in my question). Possibly, people who studied the space will see explicit examples.

Comment: @YCor: I should mention that since the Argyros-Haydon space is non-reflexive, it has even one-dimensional operators which do not attain their norms. Possibly one should look at further developments related to the Argyros-Haydon space, such as: Argyros, Spiros A.; Motakis, Pavlos, A reflexive hereditarily indecomposable space with the hereditary invariant subspace property. Proc. Lond. Math. Soc. (3) 108 (2014), no. 6, 1381–1416; http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1111.3603

Comment: I cannot vouch for the proofs, but Theorem 1 in

Baker, J. M.
[Reflexivity of operator spaces](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1982-085-03/S0002-9939-1982-0656104-0/home.html). 
Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 85 (1982), no. 3, 366–368.

claims to have an AP-free characterization of the reflexivity of $L(E,F)$. Corollary 2 in he same paper is then essentially an AP-free version of the result of Holub quoted above, and thus the answer would appear to be no. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you for the reference (which is somewhat confusing, because in the abstract the author uses AP). I shall look at it.

Comment: @ J. Alejandro Chávez-Domínguez The last paragraph of the proof of Theorem 1 in the paper of Baker is completely unclear. Why do we have $L(E,F)|E^*\otimes_\varepsilon F=(E^*\otimes_\varepsilon F)^{\circ\circ}$? (It seems to me that this equality even does not make sense.) We need to show that the quotient in the left-hand side is $0$, but this does not seem to follow from any of the statements above.